# How can I commit a Play! JPA transaction manually?

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, playframework

Usually, Play! [commits the transaction after a request completes successfully](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jpa).
What is the correct way to commit a transaction manually in Play?

```
void addPerson() {
  Person p = new Person("John", "Doe");
  p.save();

  // TODO - commit the transaction

  // Now p should have an ID
  assert p.id != null;
  usePersonIdForSomethingNasty(p.id);
}
```

Comment: Debuggin, I found that p has an ID even before the transaction is commited. I wonder how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169640/how-does-an-entity-get-an-id-before-a-transaction-is-committed-in-jpa-play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the Hibernate EntityManager by calling JPA.em().  Then, from there, you have access to the transaction (JPA.em().getTransaction()).

If you intend to manage the transaction yourself, you will want to disable Play!'s transaction handling (there is a @NoTransaction annotation you can use on the method or controller to do that).  Otherwise, Play! will try to commit the transaction at the end of the request anyway, and if you have already done that yourself, that will cause an exception.

Comment: I just found this myself ... but calling `commit()` does't seem to cause any conflicts with Play!'s transaction handling. The entity is added to the DB, and I don't get an error page.

Comment: Calling `commit()` doesn't cause conflicts in and of itself, but if you attempt any further  interactions with the DB, you need to have Play start up another Transaction for itself: `JPAPlugin.startTx(boolean readonly)`  From there, Play may as well not even know that a Transaction has already happened.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. After the request finishes without any exception, the transaction will be commited for you.

Just ensure to call "save" on all entities you want to persist at the end of transaction.

Comment: I want to commit the request manually ... I reworded the question to better reflect my intent.