# How does an entity get an ID before a transaction is committed in JPA/Play?

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169279/how-can-i-commit-a-play-jpa-transaction-manually).

It turns out that even without committing the transaction manually, before the TX is committed, the person has an ID after calling the save() method.

Isn't the database responsible of assinging the ID field? If so, how can the ID field be filled before commit? Does any communication with the DB occur before the TX is committed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the JPA is allowed to communicate with the DB before transaction commit. It can occur i.e. when you explicitly invoke `EntityManager#flush()`.

Moreover, the JPA provider is allowed to do the flush operation whenever it feels it's necessary. However, by the convenience, JPA providers delays DB operations to the time the transaction will be committed.

Some automatic ID generator strategies must hit the database to get the PK value (as far as I remember the `IDENTITY` strategy works that way).
As a contrary, the `TABLE` or `SEQUENCE` generators don't necessary need to hit the DB to get the ID value. They use the `allocationSize` parameter to ask the DB TABLE or SEQUENCE for a **batch** of IDs that will be given to new entities without further communication with the database.

Comment: Some automatic ID generator strategies must hit the database to get the PK value - does this mean that the record will get saved as soon as the session.save is invoked and not after the transaction is committed?

Answer (score 3):

Play! is flushing the persistence context (which writes changes to the database and allows it to get the generated ID) every time you save an object using the save() method on the model:

From the JPABase._save() source code:

```
if (!em().contains(this)) {
    em().persist(this);
    PlayPlugin.postEvent("JPASupport.objectPersisted", this);
}
// ...
try {
    em().flush();
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as i know, we can't get the object's id (assume it's a auto-numbered) before it's persisted.
and i personally think that it's quite dangerous to assign something which should be done by RDBMS outside it.

Comment: Why? JPA takes care of it ... and if by any chance the ID won't be availble when you commit the transaction, it will fail ... as long as you're aware that the transaction can fail (for any number of reasons), I think using the ID early is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Between begintransaction and commit, after call save or update method, you should use:

```
EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager().flush();
```

If you dont call it, the Object will be lost and cant be save to DB.

So after call it, you will take id of it in object.