# playframework manual jpa transactions inside the Jobs

Tags: jpa, transactions, playframework

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169279/how-can-i-commit-a-play-jpa-transaction-manually):

And my question is:

If I want to manage my transactions manually in the Job, what should I do?

Now I have a code and use there "@NoTransaction" like was explained in the post above:

```
@NoTransaction
@Override
public JobResult doJobWithResult() throws Exception {

    ...  

    JobResult result = new JobResult();
     try {

        //MyEntity.em().getTransaction().commit();
        MyEntity.em().getTransaction().begin();
....
```

But, but in the moment of beginning (begin()) the transaction I have still an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction already active

Thus, even if I use @NoTransaction the Job still starts its own transaction.

I can fix it like this:

```
   MyEntity.em().getTransaction().commit(); // commit previous started transaction
   MyEntity.em().getTransaction().begin();
```

But it does not seems a nice solution.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found: If use:

```
  JPAPlugin.startTx(false); // to start transaction
  JPAPlugin.closeTx(false); // to close and commit transaction
  JPAPlugin.closeTx(true); //  to roll-back transaction
```

instead of using all those JPA stuff, then everything works fine.

So, this is a solution for me. But I did not dive deep in that how the play! thinks/recognizes whether I use jpa manually or work though the plugin api .. and then decide. It looks like this, if look at startTx method:

```
  if (autoTxs) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    JPA.createContext(manager, readonly);
```

The idea is that 'better to use'  JPA-Plugin-approach when you want to manage transactions manually in Play (since JPA plugin is involved in some back-end magic, so better to be close to it in your actions)