# playframework hibernate immutable entities and version changing by merge

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, persistence, immutability

I want to make sure that

1. I may use/to have **immutable entities** with Hibernate (use play-framework)
2. That optimistic strategy works for my entities (**version is changing**) when I save/marge them back to DB

There is test:

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        // create question->answer and save them to db
        QuestionUtil.createQuestion("question1", "answer1");

        // detaching question from the hibernate session, let user to think and play with entity
        Question question1 = Question.find("title", "question1").first();    
        Question.em().detach(question1);

        // user think/edit time ... [1 minute.. 2 minutes.. coffee.. break time.. ]

        // user makes some edits in detached question, create new fresh copy (since it's immutable)
        Question editingQuestion  = new Question.Builder().copy(question1).title("updated question1").build();

        editingQuestion.merge(); 

        // get updated Question
        Question updatedQuestion = Question.find("title", "question1").first();

        assertEquals(updatedQuestion.getTitle(), "updated question1");  // OK
        assertTrue(updatedQuestion .getVersion().intValue() == 1);     // FAILS here
    }
```

**Question.**  Why version is not increased to be 1 (instead of 0) ? Is there better way to do this in general?

The head of Question class is here:

```
@Entity
public class Question extends GenericModel {

    @Version
    private Integer version;
...
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing the entity manager before finding the updating question? My guess is that Hibernate has not written anything to the database yet, and has thus not updated the version yet.

Comment: I tried to use this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384531/playframework-manual-jpa-transactions-inside-the-jobs/14384931#14384931

Wrap my calls by transactions. But then it does not safe anything to db, and different test fail (that "OK-test" is failing)

Comment: Question.em().flush(); does not help neither